# Passing pointer from C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, pointers, marshalling

I am trying to pass a 2D mask (all 0s, expect for a region of interest as 1s) from C# ( as short[]) to C++ (as unsigned short*), but I cannot get the right value in C++.

C#

```
[DllImport("StatsManager.dll", EntryPoint = "SetStatsMask")]
private static extern int SetStatsMask(IntPtr mask, int imgWidth, int imgHeight);

short[] mask;
mask = new short[8*8];
// some operation here making a ROI in mask all 1.  ex 0000111100000000 in 1D 
IntPtr maskPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(2 * mask.Length);
Marshal.Copy(mask, 0, maskPtr, mask.Length);
SetStatsMask(maskPtr, width, height);
```

C++

```
long StatsManager::SetStatsMask(unsigned short *mask, long width, long height)
{
    //create memory to store the incoming mask
    //memcpy the mask to the new buffer 
    //pMask = realloc(pMask,width*height*sizeof(unsigned short));

    long ret = TRUE;

    if (NULL == _pMask)
    {
        _pMask = new unsigned short[width * height];
    }
    else
    {
        realloc(_pMask,width*height*sizeof(unsigned short));
    }

    memcpy(mask,_pMask,width*height*sizeof(unsigned short));

    SaveBuffer(_pMask,  width,  height);

    return ret;
}
```

But all I can see for mask in C++ using watch window is `52536` instead of  `0000111100000000`, so I am wondering where I messed up? Anyone can help? Thanks.

Comment: You'd be better off declaring the `mask` parameter in C# to accept a `ushort[]` -- the array will be marshaled automatically to `unsigned short *`.

Comment: You mean the mask should be declared as ushort[] ?

Comment: Both the array you are using, and the `IntPtr` parameter should be changed to `ushort[]`, then just pass your C# array directly.  The P/Invoke layer will marshal it to a C-style array for you.  You do not need to use any of the `Marshal` methods you are using.

Comment: You mean no marshal.Copy() needed?

Comment: Correct, nor AllocHGlobal(). Just pass in the array directly. `SetStatsMask(mask, width, height);`.  (BTW this will not fix your problem, but frees you of the burden to get the array marshal code correct, including freeing your allocation.  Let the P/Invoke layer do this for you!)

Comment: I did not know there is no need to marshal when pass pointer from between managed and unmanaged. Is there any article talking about it in more detail? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sure, see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk9wyw21(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you misplaced the parameters of `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(mask,_pMask,width*height*sizeof(unsigned short));
```

As I understand you want to copy from `mask` to `_pMask`, so you should write:

```
memcpy(_pMask, mask, width*height*sizeof(unsigned short));
```

Comment: Ha, how can I miss that! Thank you, you are awesome!